# Extracting Boxes from Sudoku Solution as List of Lists

Tags: python, sudoku

```
def sqrs(seq):
  boxes = [[] for x in range(0,9)]
  j = 0
  for y in range(0, 7, 3):
    for x in range(0, 7, 3):
      for i in range(0, 3):
        boxes[j].extend(seq[y + i][x:x + 3])
      j += 1
  return boxes
```

So this function runs through a list of lists that is a 9x9 sudoku solution and transfers each 3x3 box to another list of lists. It does the job but it looks pretty ugly. Does anyone know of a slicker way to get this done?

No, I can't use numpy. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't run, since `li` isn't defined, but if I understand what you're trying to do, and you don't care about the order of the list of numbers in each box, then this works - it's up to you if you think it's slicker or not.

```
def sqrs(seq):
    indices = [(x % 3, x / 3) for x in range(0, 9)]  # Set up a list of coordinates
    boxes = [[seq[x*3+xx][y*3+yy] for xx, yy in indices] for x, y in indices]  # Use the list of coordinates both to reference the boxes and to reference the cells within the box, to reorganize the list.
    return boxes
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I knew there was a way to get a list of lists with `for` but I just couldn't get it. This helped me a lot!

Comment: Oops, do you need to `int(x / 3)` instead for setting up the coordinates list?

Comment: @chrissphinx It depends on if you're using python 2.x or python 3.x. In python 2.x, an integer divided by an integer always returns an integer.  In python 3.x, the division operator always returns a float.  If you're in python 3.x, then you're right, you do need to use `int(x / 3)`.